# Double junction arguments swapping sides

Tags: raku, perl6-junction

I'm confused about how double junctions are supposed to work.

This makes some sense:

```
say all('a', 'b', 'c') ~ any('d', 'e');
```

gives

```
all(any(ad, ae), any(bd, be), any(cd, ce))
```

This doesn't make sense:

```
say any('a', 'b', 'c') ~ all('d', 'e');
```

gives

```
all(any(da, db, dc), any(ea, eb, ec))
```

It confuses me because the letter 'a' which I would expect to be on the left of the letter 'd' is now on the right.

Comment: This smells like a bug.  Will look into it more deeply tomorrow.

Comment: It's correct that an `all` `Junction` auto-threads first, so the result structure being different is correct. However, the dis-ordering looks like a bug indeed.

Comment: Added issue: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2042

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was indeed a bug.  This has been fixed with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/4ef8433aa2 .

Thank you for your question / bug report!  The next Rakudo compiler release / next Rakudo Star release will contain this fix.